# How to acquire viewholder items in a callback class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to accumulate my recyclerview viewholder's value in another class by passing the viewholder in the callback function. On runtime, I can see the items with their values but how do I extract these values from the view holder? I want to extract the textview value in the callback method. How do I achieve this?

Here's the implementation of my viewholder class

```
public class CommentViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, IItemTouchHelperViewHolder
    {
        public TextView username;
        public ImageView userphoto;
        public TextView time;
        public TextView comment;
        public View _itemView;
        public CommentViewHolder(View view)
            : base(view)
        {
            _itemView = view;
        }


        public void OnItemClear()
        {
            _itemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
        }

        public void OnItemSelected()
        {
            _itemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGray);
        }
    }
```

Here's the callback method which get's the viewholder.

```
 public override int GetMovementFlags(Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView recyclerView, Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
    {

        if (recyclerView.GetLayoutManager() is GridLayoutManager)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post relevant code samples, it's hard to answer your question without seeing your ViewHolder implementation.

Comment: @Egor I have updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the callback gives you a `ViewHolder`, so you should be able to get the values through the provided `ViewHolder`:

```
if(viewHolder instanceof CommentViewHolder) {
    CommentViewHolder holder = (CommentViewHolder) viewHolder;
    String username = holder.username.getText();
}
```

Comment: but username is not a method of viewholder object. I get compiler error if I do that

Comment: Ah, right, so check if the `ViewHolder` returned is an instance of the `CommentViewHolder`. I updated my code.

Comment: Oh yes I think that's the right way to do it. I'll give it a shot.